# custom listener is null

Tags: java, listener, actionlistener

I have used listeners with Android and never had any problems, however today when it tried to create a simple listener in Java I am getting NullPointerException,  what is the cause of this and how can I fix it?

this includes 3 classes, ListenerMainStart.java, SendMessageClass.java, and ReceiveMessageClass.java

ListenerMainStart.java

```
public class ListenerMainStart {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new SendMessageClass();

}
}
```

SendMessageClass.java

```
public class SendMessageClass {

public OnStringRequestedListener onStringListener;

public Timer timer;

public SendMessageClass() {

    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerAction(), 3000);

}

public void SetOnStringRequestedListener(OnStringRequestedListener listener) {
       System.out.println("value of onStringListener " + onStringListener.toString());
       onStringListener = listener;

    }

public interface OnStringRequestedListener {

public void passString(String sendString);

}

public class TimerAction extends TimerTask {

@Override
public void run() {

    if (onStringListener!=null){
   // pass string to other class, ONSTRINGLISTENER IS ALWASY NULL
   onStringListener.passString("string sent from SendMessageclass");
    } else {
        System.out.println("onStringListener is null");
    }

}

}

}
```

ReceiveMessageClass.java

```
public class ReceiveMessageClass implements SendMessageClass.OnStringRequestedListener {

SendMessageClass senderClass;

public ReceiveMessageClass() {

// instantiate class
senderClass = new SendMessageClass();

   // set the listener to the class
senderClass.SetOnStringRequestedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void passString(String sendString) {

     // do action when string is sent from other class
     System.out.println("message recevied from other class is " + sendString);

}   
}
```

Comment: what is the correct or standard way to instantiate listeners in Java?

Comment: when using android i would do that in the onAttach method for a fragment, however not sure on the best way to do that here

Comment: Doesn't your program die right after new SendMessageClass()?

Comment: i does not die, but it prints out the message "onStringListener is null" and stops there

Comment: What I say is main() does not anything except new SendMessageClass()..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to call "SetOnStringRequestedListener" before you turn on your timers. As it is, that method never gets called and onStringListener never gets set. You do call that line of code in the receiver, but of course its far too late there. Your main should instantantiate both the receiver and the sender, SetOnStringRequestedListener, and then set off the timers.

```
SendMessageClass send = new SendMessageClass();
ReceiveMessageClass recv = new ReceiveMessageClass()
send.SetOnStringRequestedListener(recv)
```

**EDIT:** Then take out any code in the receiver that references the sender. The idea behind using the listener is that the two classes don't know directly about each other.

Comment: thank you, it works now.  I also started the timer from the main method.  Java and Android have to be approached in a different way.